# Money saved from the Philippines

Tags: united-states, savings, foreign-income, philippines

I have saved up $45,000.00 in the bank in the Philippines and I would like to bring them back to US as a returning US Citizen. Will I be taxed for this money I saved up?

Comment: As a US citizen, have you been filing tax returns during your time abroad?

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is that there is no US tax due if all you are doing is moving assets held abroad to the US. Whether you are a "returning" US citizen (or will continue your residence in the Philippines) is not relevant to this.

The long answer is that you may be liable for a lot of other fines and taxes if you have not been doing any of several things correctly. As a US citizen, you are required to declare your worldwide income on your US income tax returns.

- Have you been filing
  US income tax returns during your time abroad? and have you been declaring the income that you have received from non-US sources each
  year? This includes wages, interest, dividends, capital gains,
  rental income from real estate, gambling income, lottery winnings, 
  Nobel prizes, *everything*. If you have been paying income tax to other countries on this income, then
  it is generally possible to get a deduction for this tax payment from
  the income that will be taxed by the US (or a credit for the tax
  payment against your US Federal income tax liability) depending on
  the existence of tax treaties or (when the US Senate refuses to
  approve a tax treaty) a Double Taxation Avoidance Agreement between
  the US and other countries. In some cases, foreign *earned* income
  up to a certain limit is not taxed by the US at all.
- Even if you have been filing US income tax returns correctly, and
  can thus account for the $45,000 in your savings account, or you
  received that money as a gift or inheritance and can account for it
  on that basis, have you been filing
  reports with the US Treasury since the year when the
  *total* value of *all* your foreign
  bank accounts and other financial assets (stocks and bonds etc
  but not real estate) first exceeded $10,000?  In prior years,
  this was a matter of filling out and submitting Form TD F 90-22.1
  but more recently (since 2010?), you need to fill out and submit FinCEN Form 114.
  Have you been submitting the required documentation all along? Note that
  there are severe penalties for failure to fine FinCEN Form 114, and
  these penalties do not get waived by tax treaties.
- There also are reporting requirements if you received payments
  from a foreign trust or had set up a foreign trust of your own, but
  this is more uncommon and I won't bother putting in the details.

In summary, you might (or you might not) have several other tax
or legal issues to
worry about than just taxes on the transfer of your money from the Philippines to
the US.